# Nextjs Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at localhost

Tags: next.js

Error:

> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/layout failed. (timeout: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js)

I keep getting this error on startup (npm run dev), reloading the page fixes it, allowing the app to run with no other issue.

I know the issue isn't coming from the rootlayout but I'll post it just in case,

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Provider from "@/components/Provider";
import { UserContextProvider } from "@/contexts/UserContext";
import { DarkModeContextProvider } from "@/contexts/DarkMode";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
    title: "Gelianthus Tries NextJS #03",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <link
                    rel="icon"
                    href="/sunflower_logo.webp"
                    sizes="any"
                />
                <link
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                />
            </head>
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <Provider>
                    <UserContextProvider>
                        <DarkModeContextProvider>{children}</DarkModeContextProvider>
                    </UserContextProvider>
                </Provider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

I deleted the static folder where the error is coming from, doing so removes the problem temporarily. At least for 1 server restart, but after that, the folder would return and so does the error.